# Wordpress get values outside function

Tags: wordpress

I need get the value of function that use in wordpress , this function add the value in other page of wordpress using the API add_action , i put the script :

```
<?php
function wplogincontrol()
{
$a=2;
}

if ($a=="2")
{
header"Location:http://www.google.com");
}

add_action('login_head', 'wplogincontrol');
?>
```

If use this never can do works and i think use global var and use this :

```
    <?php
    function wplogincontrol()
    {
global $a;
    $a=2;
    }


global $a;
    if ($a=="2")
    {
    header"Location:http://www.google.com");
    }

    add_action('login_head', 'wplogincontrol');
    ?>


Also i try with $GLOBALS['a'];
```

But never can get works and can´t get the value outside the function , i try this because if use header location inside function and no work me and give error of header , by this i need get the value outside of function and i see works fine for redirect of header

It´s possible get this value ? , Thak´s , Regards

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something like this ?

```
<?php
function myfunc()
{
 $a=2;
 return $a;
}
function wplogincontrol(){
    $val = myfunc();
    if ($val=="2")
    {
        header"Location: http://www.google.com");
        exit;
    }
}

add_action('login_head', 'wplogincontrol');
?>
```